# Optimizing a python function with numpy arrays

Tags: python, function, loops, optimization, numpy

I have been trying to optimize a python script I wrote for the last two days. Using several profiling tools (cProfile, line_profiler etc.) I narrowed down the issue to the following function below.

`df` is a numpy array with 3 columns and +1,000,000 rows (data type is float). Using line_profiler, I found out that the function spends most of the time whenever it needs to access the numpy array.

`full_length += head + df[rnd_truck, 2]`

and

`full_weight += df[rnd_truck,1]`

take most of the time, followed by

`full_length = df[rnd_truck,2]`

`full_weight = df[rnd_truck,1]`

lines.

As far as I see the bottleneck is caused by the access time the function tries to grab a number from the numpy array.

When I run the function as `MonteCarlo(df, 15., 1000.)` it takes 37 seconds to call the function for 1,000,000 times in a i7 3.40GhZ 64bit Windows machine with 8GB RAM. In my application, I need to run it for 1,000,000,000 to ensure convergence, which brings the execution time to more than an hour. I tried using the `operator.add` method for the summation lines, but it did not help me at all. It looks like I have to figure out a faster way to access this numpy array.

Any ideas would be welcome!

```
def MonteCarlo(df,head,span):
    # Pick initial truck
    rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
    full_length = df[rnd_truck,2]
    full_weight = df[rnd_truck,1]

    # Loop using other random truck until the bridge is full
    while 1:
        rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
        full_length += head + df[rnd_truck, 2]
        if full_length > span:
            break
        else:
            full_weight += df[rnd_truck,1]

    # Return average weight per feet on the bridge
    return(full_weight/span)
```

Below is a portion of the `df` numpy array I am using:

```
In [31] df
Out[31]: 
array([[  12. ,  220.4,  108.4],
       [  11. ,  220.4,  106.2],
       [  11. ,  220.3,  113.6],
       ..., 
       [   4. ,   13.9,   36.8],
       [   3. ,   13.7,   33.9],
       [   3. ,   13.7,   10.7]])
```

Comment: What do the inputs represent, and what are their dimensions?

Comment: Since it's only 3 columns, I wonder if you'd be better off with 3 separate arrays.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you don't have a single vectorized operation in this function. You could save a lot of time by randomly picking a large number of trucks at once and having NumPy vectorize the addition of lengths and weights for you.

Comment: Can you show a small check of `df`, or a way to generate this data.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right, I do not use any vectorized operation in this function. I use it somewhere else, out of this function, and it does its job well in terms of speed. Do you think using a list for such an operation would be faster? I can convert the array columns to lists then feed them to the function.

Comment: @user2357112 I do not know how many trucks I would need to break the loop using the `if full_length > span` check. Trucks are 60ft long as an avarage, that `span` argument is the bridge length. I can make an educated guess, since I do not think the `while` loop would be called more than 20 times. Do you think selecting 20 trucks at once, or each truck in every cycle would make a difference?

Comment: @Jim, using three separate Numpy vectors reduced the run time to 29 seconds on average.

Comment: If the loop won't run more than about 20 times in the common case, I'm not sure how much it'd help. There's a good chance it'll help, though. You might also try running 1000000 simulations in parallel.

Comment: @Ophion, I have added a portion of the `df` array at the bottom of the post.

Comment: If it's a list of triples, why not just do one fetch of the triple and then access that for the other info?  It would only be one access into the big list.  trip = df[rnd_truck]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by other people, this isn't vectorized at all, so your slowness is really due to slowness of the Python interpreter. [Cython](http://cython.org) can help you a lot here with minimal changes:

```
>>> %timeit MonteCarlo(df, 5, 1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48 us per loop

>>> %timeit MonteCarlo_cy(df, 5, 1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.67 us per loop
```

where `MonteCarlo_cy` is just (in the IPython notebook, after `%load_ext cythonmagic`):

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def MonteCarlo_cy(double[:, ::1] df, double head, double span):
    # Pick initial truck
    cdef long n = df.shape[0]
    cdef long rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0, n)
    cdef double full_weight = df[rnd_truck, 1]
    cdef double full_length = df[rnd_truck, 2]

    # Loop using other random truck until the bridge is full
    while True:
        rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0, n)
        full_length += head + df[rnd_truck, 2]
        if full_length > span:
            break
        else:
            full_weight += df[rnd_truck, 1]

    # Return average weight per feet on the bridge
    return full_weight / span
```

Comment: To speed this up further (and allow [simple parallelization with OpenMP](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html)), you might want to switch out the calls to `np.random.randint` with some C-level random number generator. [Here are some suggestions.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.user/9531)

Answer (score 2):

Using cython to compile the function gives a very substantial improvement to runtime.

In a separate file called "funcs.pyx" I have the following code:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


def MonteCarlo(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] df, float head, float span):
    # Pick initial truck
    cdef int rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
    cdef float full_length = df[rnd_truck,2]
    cdef float full_weight = df[rnd_truck,1]
    # Loop using other random truck until the bridge is full
    while 1:
        rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
        full_length += head + df[rnd_truck, 2]
        if full_length > span:
            break
        else:
            full_weight += df[rnd_truck,1]
    # Return average weight per feet on the bridge
    return(full_weight/span)
```

Everything is the same except for the type declarations in front of the variables.

Here's the file I used to test it out:

```
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install(reload_support=True, setup_args={'include_dirs':[np.get_include()]})
import funcs

def MonteCarlo(df,head,span):
    # Pick initial truck
    rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
    full_length = df[rnd_truck,2]
    full_weight = df[rnd_truck,1]
    # Loop using other random truck until the bridge is full
    while 1:
        rnd_truck = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
        full_length += head + df[rnd_truck, 2]
        if full_length > span:
            break
        else:
            full_weight += df[rnd_truck,1]
    # Return average weight per feet on the bridge
    return(full_weight/span)

df = np.random.rand(1000000,3)
reload(funcs)
%timeit [funcs.MonteCarlo(df, 15, 1000) for i in range(10000)]
%timeit [MonteCarlo(df, 15, 1000) for i in range(10000)]
```

I only ran it 10000 times, but even so, there's a huge improvement.

```
16:42:30: In [31]: %timeit [funcs.MonteCarlo(df, 15, 1000) for i in range(10000)]
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop

16:42:37: In [32]: %timeit [MonteCarlo(df, 15, 1000) for i in range(10000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.75 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Something to point out is Monte Carlo is embarrassingly parallel. No matter which solution you pick you should be doing something to parallelize it. Using @Dougal's answer.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def RunVMC(n):
    return MonteCarlo_cy(df,head,span)


pool=Pool(processes=4)

%timeit [MonteCarlo_cy(df,15,1000) for x in range(1000000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 3.89 s per loop

#Pool @ 4
%timeit out=pool.map(RunVMC,xrange(1000000))
1 loops, best of 3: 0.973 s per loop

#Pool @ 8
%timeit out=pool.map(RunVMC,xrange(1000000))
1 loops, best of 3: 568 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes, this should definitely be run in parallel. Note that this approach makes one copy per worker of the (fairly large) `df` array, though. Using Cython, killing the small bit of GIL-needing code for the RNG as I mentioned in a comment on my answer, and then using `prange` is more memory-efficient. (Also, it's worth noting that your `RunVMC` function seems to have no purpose over just calling `MonteCarlo_cy`....)

Comment: I updated the function to what it should have been, using `df`, `head`, and `span` as global variables. The best way I have seen to pass additional arguments with `map` is using `itertools` which has always seemed more of hassle then its worth.

Comment: @Ophion this is the only part I could not work out. In my home machine (running OS X) the multiprocessing code works without any problem, and gives me a 100% increase in speed. In my work mahcine (running Win 7) I get an `Import Error: No module named montecarlo_v5b` error in the kernel window (not in the ipython GUI), which goes on infinitely, as soon as I enter the `pool=Pool(processes=4)` statement. Is this a Windows quirk? `montecarlo_v5b` is the name of my py file.

Comment: @marillion Im sorry I have no experience with windows, I know there are some quirks compared to linux- a google search should probably return the answer.

Comment: @Ophion as far as I understand, I have to use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement somewhere in the code, but not exactly sure where. Well, I have already spent too much time on optimizing this function, and there's still lots to do, so I should better learn how to use the multiprocessing module in Windows in another project :) But as I said, it works in OS X (or any OS that supports forking probably) like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to another Python variant. [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) is a bit faster than Python, and in some cases [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is *a lot* faster. Give them both a try.

Comment: I don't think either of those support NumPy. (I'm not sure whether the OP is actually taking advantage of NumPy, though.)

Comment: PyPy supports a subset of Numpy, appropriately called NumPyPy.

Comment: Oh, they started work on that? I thought they were still just gathering funding to hire someone. It doesn't look ready enough that I'd want to use it, but having NumPy support in PyPy will be great once it's done.

Comment: I was planning to try PyPy, however, I do not have admin privileges to install it on the computer I am using. I am stuck with the stock python interpreter :)